# How to switch between Ivy completion styles?

Tags: ivy

There are three [Ivy completion styles](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#completion-styles):

```
ivy--regex-plus
ivy--regex-ignore-order
ivy--regex-fuzzy
```

C-o (hydra-ivy/body) m toggles between ivy "ivy--regex-plus" and "ivy--regex-fuzzy".

How to switch to ivy--regex-ignore-order completion style?

For example, if I wanted a list of all functions that contain the string "spell",
from help describe functions I would: enter "spell" and switch to ivy--regex-ignore-order.

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Comment: The link you provide lists 5 possible regexp builder functions. What is your desired behaviour? Providing more toggle keys, for switching between more possible builders, or changing `m` (`ivy-toggle-fuzzy`) to rotate between them all?

Comment: Please, changing m (matcher) to rotate between three completion styles: ivy--regex-plus, ivy--regex-ignore-order, ivy-toggle-fuzzy

Comment: For your specific use case of finding functions containing "spell" I don't think you need to change the matching style at all? Just do `C-h f` and search for either `spell` or `^ spell` -- that is, delete the leading `^` or add a space after it. That said, I think your suggestion to be able to toggle matching styles is a good one and perhaps should be a feature request for ivy.

Comment: I added this as a feature request: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1093,

Comment: @Basil Looks like abo-abo likes the suggestion (link above). Would you like to create a patch request to ivy for your changes? Otherwise I can submit one. I'm thinking the builders list could just have a cons cell with the display name to use in the dynamic hydra docstring, so ivy--matcher-desc could look it up.

Comment: @glucas You have my blessing - I don't expect to be able to look into this for a few weeks. :) The alist suggestion sounds like an elegant and canonical approach. The only issue / philosophical question with this is whether such a list belongs in `ivy.el` proper or in `ivy-hydra.el`. For our purposes I would say the latter, but that requires `ivy-hydra.el` to stay up to date with `ivy.el` on this. Then again, there are always fallback/default values, and `ivy.el` is unlikely to change dramatically in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in this answer is now part of Ivy: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/ae438ff62fa3d9b98d899afc0e97c13be2148725

Within `ivy-hydra`, the `m` key is bound to the command `ivy-toggle-fuzzy`, which is hard-coded to toggle the variable `ivy--regex-function` between the regexp-building functions `ivy--regex-fuzzy` and `ivy--regex-plus`.

The `ivy-hydra` panel is similarly limited by the function `ivy--matcher-desc` to describing `ivy--regex-fuzzy` as "fuzzy" and all other values as "ivy".

I am not familiar with `hydra` and whether it facilitates hot-swapping key bindings and commands, so my only suggestion (other than possibly submitting a feature request to the [`ivy`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) project) is to override the aforementioned functions to exhibit the desired behaviour:

```el
(defvar my-ivy-builders '(ivy--regex-plus
                          ivy--regex-ignore-order
                          ivy--regex-fuzzy)
  "Preferred values for `ivy--regex-function'.")

(define-advice ivy--matcher-desc (:override () my-expand-matchers)
  "Return a brief description of `ivy--regex-function'."
  (pcase ivy--regex-function
    ('ivy--regex-fuzzy        "fuzzy")
    ('ivy--regex-ignore-order "order")
    ('ivy--regex-plus         "plus")
    (_                        "other")))

(define-advice ivy-toggle-fuzzy (:override () my-rotate-builders)
  "Slide `ivy--regex-function' across `my-ivy-builders'."
  (when my-ivy-builders
    (setq ivy--old-re nil)
    (setq ivy--regex-function
          (or (cadr (memq ivy--regex-function my-ivy-builders))
              (car my-ivy-builders)))))
```

Here, `my-ivy-builders` holds all preferred regexp building functions which are suitable as values of the variable `ivy--regex-function`. The `ivy--matcher-desc` advice simply adds support for describing more such functions with a human-readable name. You can name them whatever you like, but make sure they fit within 5 columns, otherwise the `ivy-hydra` panel's formatting will become distorted. Finally, the `ivy-toggle-fuzzy` advice slides `ivy--regex-function` across its permitted values as listed in `my-ivy-builders`. You can change the initial order of `my-ivy-builders` to match both your taste and your default value for `ivy--regex-function`.

I use `:override` advice instead of redefining the functions with `defun` because the former gets reported by the help system (i.e. `describe-function`). Note that `define-advice` was only added in Emacs 25.1; under Emacs 24 the advice should be written more like

```el
(defvar my-ivy-builders '(ivy--regex-plus
                          ivy--regex-ignore-order
                          ivy--regex-fuzzy)
  "Preferred values for `ivy--regex-function'.")

(defun my-ivy-matcher-descs ()
  "Return a brief description of `ivy--regex-function'."
  (pcase ivy--regex-function
    ('ivy--regex-fuzzy        "fuzzy")
    ('ivy--regex-ignore-order "order")
    ('ivy--regex-plus         "plus")
    (_                        "other")))

(advice-add 'ivy--matcher-desc :override #'my-ivy-matcher-descs)

(defun my-ivy-rotate-builders ()
  "Slide `ivy--regex-function' across `my-ivy-builders'."
  (when my-ivy-builders
    (setq ivy--old-re nil)
    (setq ivy--regex-function
          (or (cadr (memq ivy--regex-function my-ivy-builders))
              (car my-ivy-builders)))))

(advice-add 'ivy-toggle-fuzzy :override #'my-rotate-builders)
```

I think plain (') quotes were also not always supported by `pcase`, so you may need to change them to backquotes (`).

#### Update

Further to the helpful comments by glucas below, you can forgo advising the function `ivy-toggle-fuzzy` and instead replace it with an adjusted `my-ivy-rotate-builders` in the `hydra` keymap under the default keybinding of `m`:

```el
(defvar my-ivy-builders '(ivy--regex-plus
                          ivy--regex-ignore-order
                          ivy--regex-fuzzy)
  "Preferred values for `ivy--regex-function'.")

(define-advice ivy--matcher-desc (:override () my-expand-matchers)
  "Return a brief description of `ivy--regex-function'."
  (pcase ivy--regex-function
    ('ivy--regex-fuzzy        "fuzzy")
    ('ivy--regex-ignore-order "order")
    ('ivy--regex-plus         "plus")
    (_                        "other")))

(defun my-ivy-rotate-builders ()
  "Slide `ivy--regex-function' across `my-ivy-builders'."
  (interactive)
  (when my-ivy-builders
    (setq ivy--old-re nil)
    (setq ivy--regex-function
          (or (cadr (memq ivy--regex-function my-ivy-builders))
              (car my-ivy-builders)))))

(with-eval-after-load 'ivy-hydra
  (define-key hydra-ivy/keymap "m" #'my-ivy-rotate-builders))
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with `hydra` can also suggest an easy way to modify the `hydra-ivy` hint/panel in-place instead of advising `ivy--matcher-desc`.

Comment: Wow Basil, that's impressive.  You have inspired me to learn elisp.
Unfortunately the ivy--regex-ignore-order option is not working.
I tested this on help describe functions ispell:
"order" appears in the matcher rotation, but "ispell" function does not appear in the list (the "order" list is identical to the "plus" list).

Comment: I've just tested this and it works great for me. Note that you can just rebind "m" in the `hydra-ivy/keymap` rather than using advice, so I've made `my-ivy-rotate-builders` a function of its own.

Comment: @user2867994 Can you explain your test case a bit more? It sounds like you are searching for a single string, in which case order is not relevant. Also note that if you're matching a regex that starts with `^` (which ivy does insert by default...) then that will only match the beginning of the string even when using `ivy--regex-ignore-order`. Try this instead: `C-h f buffer spell` (note no `^` char) which will match nothing, then rotate the matchers and see that it now matches e.g. `ispell-buffer`.

Comment: @glucas So that's what the '^' is for!  After removing the '^', Basil's functions work great.  Sorry, my test case from 3 comments up has a typo.  The test case should say: from help describe functions "spell", "order" appears in the matcher rotation, but "ispell" function does not appear in the list.

Comment: Ivy is using a regular expression to find the matches, and `^foo` would mean "match strings starting with foo". Usually when I'm searching for a substring I just hit space: with `^ foo` ivy will find matches with foo anywhere, rather than at the beginning. Order becomes relevant when you have multiple substrings and don't know which order they might appear in, so `foo bar` could match "bar-foo" or "foo-bar". You can use other regular expression characters with ivy, e.g. you could use `foo$` to only match things that end with "foo".

Comment: Thanks for the explanations glucas.
ivy--regex-plus matches input regex tokens in order.
ivy–regex-ignore-order matches input regex tokens regardless of order.
So ivy–regex-ignore-order and ivy–regex-plus will have identical results if there is only one input token, as in my "spell" example.
ivy–regex-ignore-order option is useful as a stricter fuzzy search.

Comment: Indeed, thank you @glucas for the helpful and insightful comments. I have updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: I changed the order of completion styles to:   (pcase ivy--regex-function
    ('ivy--regex-plus         "order")
    ('ivy--regex-ignore-order "igord")
    ('ivy--regex-fuzzy        "fuzzy")
    (_                        "other"))).
But when I open hydra, it lists matcher "igord", were I was expecting matcher "order" to be default.  How to set default value for ivy--regex-function?

Comment: @user2867994 The code you modified is only responsible for returning a human-readable description of the current `ivy--regex-function`, so the order of the mutually exclusive `pcase` cases does not matter (bar the final, catchall case). What value do you want to set `ivy--regex-function` to? It defaults to `ivy--regex-plus`. I think the easiest way to set its default is via `(with-eval-after-load 'ivy (setf (alist-get t ivy-re-builders-alist) <DEFAULT>))`.